# Execute Protractor test in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, eclipse, protractor

I am new to Protractor.I want to execute the tests of Protractor in Eclipse. I have installed npm,protractor locally,AngularEclipse,nodeclipse and Converted my project in the AngularJs Project.Now i am able to execute my test.js file through command prompt using command protractor config.js. But when i am using eclipse option Run as>Protractor it gives following:

[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
D:\Protractor_WorkSpace\Protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
    at Object.win32.join (path.js:221:5)
    at D:\Protractor_WorkSpace\Protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\safari.js:84:29
    at Object. (D:\Protractor_WorkSpace\Protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\safari.js:98:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

Answer (score 0):

@User : Can you try adding 'node-modules' into your current project and configure 'Run/Build' path for protractor.? I think this issue due to unavailability of 'internal/module.js'.

Comment: node-modules is already into my current Project.But i did not get which Run/Build Path are you talking about?